# Adding labels and comments to a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

Fellows and folks!

I have been fighting to draw what's on the picture for a long time:

[image]

I cannot draw those 3 arrows that are pointing to the same comment. Plus, the other two arrows that are pointing to letters "i" and "j". Could you please give me a hand?

This is what I have done so far:

```
​`\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
row 5/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},
column 4/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 6/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 7/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},]
{   & & & R & & ? & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\ 
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & ? & & R& & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & &|[draw,fill=blue!20]| R& & &  \\};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\dots,$i$, ,$j$,\dots,$m-1$,$m$}
\node[above, font=\scriptsize] at (A-1-\xi.north) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\vdots,$u$,\vdots,$n-1$,$n$}
\node[left, font=\scriptsize] at (A-\xi-1.west) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i in {2,4,7}
\draw[dashed] ([shift={(.5mm,-.5mm)}]A-\i-4.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-.5mm,.5mm)}]A-\i-6.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{item based }
\end{figure}`
```

[image]

It does not look good at all. Plus I have done the other version, where I have to calculate the similarity between rows. All I have to do is to transpose the matrix:

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
row 5/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},
column 4/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 6/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 7/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},]
{   & & & R & & ? & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\ 
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & ? & & R& & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & &|[draw,fill=blue!20]| R& & &  \\};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\dots,$i$, ,$j$,\dots,$m-1$,$m$}
\node[above, font=\scriptsize] at (A-1-\xi.north) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\vdots,$u$,\vdots,$n-1$,$n$}
\node[left, font=\scriptsize] at (A-\xi-1.west) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i in {2,4,7}
\draw[dashed] ([shift={(.5mm,-.5mm)}]A-\i-4.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-.5mm,.5mm)}]A-\i-6.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{item based }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possible option, using the `fit` and `positioning` libraries, and relative coordinates for the arrows on top. See comments in the code, ask if I should expand on anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
matrix,
positioning, % added
fit          % added
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
row 5/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},
row 4/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
row 6/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 7/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},]
{
   & & &  & &  &   \\
   & & &  & &  &   \\
   & & &  & &  &   \\
 |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R  & &|[draw,fill=blue!20]|R &  & & ? & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R  \\
   & & &  & &  &   \\
 |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R  & &|[draw,fill=blue!20]|R &  & & R & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R  \\
   & & &  & &  &   \\
   & & &  & &  &   \\
   & & &  & &  &   \\
};

% draw the box below
\node [draw,
       text width=3cm,
       below=of A,
       name=textbox
       ] {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc. etc. ad infinitum};


\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\vdots,$i$, ,$j$,\vdots,$m-1$,$m$}
    \node[left, font=\scriptsize,name=l-\xi] at (A-\xi-1.west) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\dots,$u$,\dots,$n-1$,$n$}
   \node[above, font=\scriptsize] at (A-1-\xi.north) {\i\strut};

\foreach \i in {1,3,7}
    {
    % use the fit library instead of drawing box manually, then you get a node you can refer to
    \node [fit=(A-4-\i)(A-6-\i), inner sep=-0.5mm, draw, dashed, name=R\i] {};
    % draw arrow from textbox node
    \draw [<-] (R\i.south) -- (textbox);
    }


% draw arrows from the nodes using the names defined with the modification of the loop above
% and relative coordinates. Add helper coordinate on the first arrow 
\draw [<-] (l-4) -- coordinate[pos=0.6] (s1) ++(-15mm,0);
\draw [<-] (l-6) -- ++(-15mm,0);
% draw arrow between the helper coordinate s1 and the point that has the x-coordinate of t-6 and the y-coordinate of s1
\draw [<->] (s1) -- node[fill=white,font=\scriptsize,inner sep=1pt] {$s_{i,j}=?$}  (l-6 -| s1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
row 5/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},
column 4/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 6/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 7/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},]
{   & & & R & & ? & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\ 
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & ? & & R& & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & &|[draw,fill=blue!20]| R& & &  \\};

% draw the box on the right
\node [draw,
       text width=3cm,
       right=of A,
       name=textbox
       ] {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc. etc. ad infinitum};


\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\dots,$i$, ,$j$,\dots,$m-1$,$m$}
    % added name=t-\xi to the following
    \node[above, font=\scriptsize, name=t-\xi] at (A-1-\xi.north) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\vdots,$u$,\vdots,$n-1$,$n$}
    \node[left, font=\scriptsize] at (A-\xi-1.west) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i in {2,4,7}
    {
    % use the fit library instead of drawing box manually, then you get a node you can refer to
    \node [fit=(A-\i-4)(A-\i-6), inner sep=-0.5mm, draw, dashed, name=R\i] {};
    % draw arrow from textbox node
    \draw [<-] (R\i.east) -- (textbox);
    }


% draw arrows from the nodes using the names defined with the modification of the loop above
% and relative coordinates. Add helper coordinate on the first arrow 
\draw [<-] (t-4) -- coordinate[pos=0.6] (s1) ++(0,15mm);
\draw [<-] (t-6) -- ++(0,15mm);
% draw arrow between the helper coordinate s1 and the point that has the x-coordinate of t-6 and the y-coordinate of s1
\draw [<->] (s1) -- node[fill=white,font=\scriptsize,inner sep=1pt] {$s_{i,j}=?$}  (t-6 |- s1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to do the same but transposing the matrix!

Comment: @naveganteX Well, you can use exactly the same techniques for that.

Comment: @naveganteX Basically to transpose the matrix you just have to do it by hand I think, i.e. rewrite it. And change styles/anchors etc. that refer to rows so they refer to columns, and vice versa.

Comment: @naveganteX Did a quick transpose, see updated answer. Might have gotten some things wrong though, but you'll probably be able to fix that, considering where you had gotten to in the first place.

Comment: It looks awesome! Taking into account Marmot's nice answer, It would be awesome if you could avoid these lines "--", meaning, dash lines and make them look like Marmot's lines, which are continuous dotted lines!!!

Comment: @naveganteX Replace `dashed` with `rounded corners`.

Comment: How can I change the font size? Because the box is too big!

Comment: @naveganteX You already know how to do that ... At least you had done it two places in your original code. `font=\small` (or some other font size switch)

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to Torbjørn T's nice answer except that the border of the comment is as in your figure (and drawn via `path picture`, i.e. you can make it a style if you use such things more often).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt, 
anchor=center},row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
row 5/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},
column 4/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 6/.style = {nodes={fill=lightgray}},
column 7/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},]
{   & & & R & & ? & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & & &  \\ 
    & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & ? & & R& & &  \\
    & & & |[draw,fill=blue!20]|R & &|[draw,fill=blue!20]| R& & &  \\};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\dots,$i$, ,$j$,\dots,$m-1$,$m$}
\node[above, font=\scriptsize] at (A-1-\xi.north) {\i\strut};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\vdots,$u$,\vdots,$n-1$,$n$}
\node[left, font=\scriptsize] at (A-\xi-1.west) {\i\strut};
\node[right=1cm of A,align=left,text width=4cm,path picture={
\draw ([xshift=1em,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]path picture bounding box.north west) -|
 ([xshift=\pgflinewidth,yshift=\pgflinewidth]path picture bounding box.south west) -- ++ (1em,0);}] (txt){%
Some very long text about ducks, koalas and marmots which is very long and deals
with ducks, koalas and marmots. \dots}; 
\foreach \i  in {2,4,7}
{\node[draw,rounded corners,fit=(A-\i-4)(A-\i-6),inner xsep=-1ex,
inner ysep=-0.3ex] (F-\i){};
\draw[-latex] (txt) -- (F-\i.east);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The one! Thank you very much! Is there any way that you can transpose the matrix and draw the second model?

Comment: @naveganteX AFAIK there is no automatic way, matrices are very immune to transformations. So one needs to do what [Torbjørn T. is saying: transpose it by rewriting it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490705/adding-labels-and-comments-to-a-matrix/490712?noredirect=1#comment1239054_490711). Any attempt to use `transform canvas` will extremely likely fail at a given point.